# iOS Swift UICollectionView Photo browsing - how to stop cancel DispatchQueue when cells not visible

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

I have a photo browsing app. I'm using UICollectionView to display list of photos. Photos are extracted from my website by downloading the HTML source of the website and get photo URLs. For each cell in UICollectionView, I have to download HTML source from different URL and extract photos from that. Here's my cellForItem function:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "siteAlbumCellID", for: indexPath) as! AlbumCell
    ...
    getListPhotoURLs(album: album, updateSite: updateSite, handler: { [weak self] (photos) in
                                guard let ss = self else { return }
                                if let photos = photos{
                                    if photos.count > 0{
                                        ...
                                    }
                                }else{
                                    cell.aiView.stopAnimating()
                                    cell.ivPhoto.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "cover")
                                }
                            })
     ...
}
```

I only let the webpage to be downloaded once by using cache after the html souce is downloaded.
and here's the getListPhotoURLs function:

```
func getHTMLSource(url: String, cookie: String? = nil, handler: @escaping (_ result:String?) -> Void){
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        guard let myURL = URL(string: url) else {
            print("Error: \(url) doesn't seem to be a valid URL")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                handler(nil)
            }
            return
        }
        do {
            var myHTMLString = try String(contentsOf: myURL, encoding: .utf8)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                handler(myHTMLString)
            }
        } catch let error {
            print("Error: \(error)")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                handler(nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When scrollview reaches the bottom, the app will load more data from server, here's where the problem arises: when I scroll all the way down to the bottom, the app is still downloading all HTML sources for all cells, and I have to wait for a while before the next page data to be loaded. This is because many HTML download task is running, and that uses lots of internet bandwidth

I want that when users scroll the collection view, and those unfinished html downloading tasks need to stop the getHTMLSource function for cells that are not visible, to save internet bandwidth for other html download task of visible cells.

Answer (score 0):

NSOperationQueue is best approach to cancel all the operations .But if you want to do it through DispathQueue.We can cancel items added in Dispatch Queue by having as workItem

```
let queue = DispatchQueue.main
    var item: DispatchWorkItem!
    // create work item
    item = DispatchWorkItem{
        //perform functionality
    }
    queue.async(execute: item)
```

cancel work item by calling cancel

```
 item.cancel()
```